# Are there idiomatic best practices for modifying structs in C?

Tags: c

Let's say you want to make a function `f` in C that transforms some struct, say `struct s1`.

Are there best practices/idioms in modern C over whether it is better for your function `f` to receive/return **copies** of the struct vs. **pointers** to the struct?

For example, here are some possible type signatures for `f` (and I'm sure there's more that I'm missing):

```
struct s1 f(struct s1)
struct* s1 f(struct* s1)
void f(struct *s1)
```

In general, do people try to steer away from some of these type signatures vs others?

Comment: Depends on the size of the structure, and whether the intent is to make a copy, or simply modify some values within the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last is idiomatic.

C people place a high value on efficiency, because that's usually the reason they are using C rather than a higher-level language, and passing a pointer is faster than pushing a whole structure on the stack. Modifying a structure in-place is similarly a lot faster than taking a copy, allocating heap memory, and returning it. Also C doesn't have a good way of distinguishing deep from shallow copies, so the copy method leads to the question of what happens to pointer members.

However you will see all three methods in real C code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question about working on copies entirely depends on the intent - given that cloning and changing the clone is very different from modifying the original. So that rules out #1

If we are modifying the original then I would choose the last signature. Its obvious that this is working on the original, the second one might be cloning or not, its not clear given that it retuirns a pointer to some struct